# Optional group following non-greedy group

Tags: python, regex

I'm not completely new to regexes, I've used them on many occasions, but mostly without the 'fancy' stuff like lookaheads and such.
I need a single regex that can match the following two patterns:

1. `PrefTextValue13`
2. `PrefText`

The string 'Pref' is always there and I want to ignore it. 'Text' is a group that I need and it is matched by `[\w\d_]+`. The string 'Value', when there should be ignored, but when there it must be followed by a number `(\d+)` that I need to capture as a group. Both 'Value' and number are optional.

Examples:
For case 1) I need to match 'Text' as group 1 and 13 as group 2; for 2) I wan't to match only Text.
My attempt (one of many) was:

```
re.compile("Pref([\w\d_]+)(Value)?(\d+)?") or 
re.compile("Pref([\w\d_]+?)(?:Value)?(?:?=Value)(\d+)?")
```

but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
re.compile(r'^Pref(\w+?)(?:Value(\d+))?$')
```

Note that `[\w\d_]` is same as `\w`.

You have to make `Value\d+` collectively as optional. For that you have to make them a group. But since you don't want to capture them, you can use a non-capturing group. Also, you can make the `\d+` part in it a capturing group, so that you can get that part.

The issue with `"Pref(\w+)(?:Value(\d+))?"` is that, `\w+` will match everything till the end, and satisfy the regex, as `Value\d+` part is optional. So, everything will be captured in `\w+`. So, you have to make it reluctant - `\w+?`.

Now, your desired output is in *group 1* and *group 2*. For the 2<sup>nd</sup> case, *group 2* will be `null`.

Comment: The problem with this is that all of `TextValue13` will match `[\w\d_]+`.

Comment: @Barmar. Crap. Completely missed that.

Comment: For the two inputs ´PrefApples´ and ´PrefOrangesValue2´, match.groups() return ('Apples', None) and ('OrangesValue2', None) respectively. For oranges I was expecting ('Oranges', '2')

Comment: And the first group can't be non-greedy because it would stop then at the first letter

Comment: @user1514631. Non-greedy won't help here, as I explained in answer.

Comment: The last regex is not working also. I'm using this test: <br>`import re r = re.compile("Pref(\w+)|Pref(\w+?)(?:Value(\d+))") s1 = "PrefApples" s2 = "PrefOrangesValue2" x = r.match(s1) print s1, x if x: print x.groups() x = r.match(s2) print s2, x if x: print x.groups()`

Comment: @user1514631. Ok, let me test some regex with your strings. I'll be right back.

Comment: @user1514631. Edited post. You can try the regex now.

Comment: @RohitJain. It only returns the first matched characters (A for Apples and O) as the first group. A non-greedy first group doesn't work at all, I've tried it myself in several variations, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @RohitJain. This one works as expected. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If _Pref_ and _Value_ fields values are empty then use **Pref(\w*?)(?:Value(\d*))?$**